# debugging Unix pipe with gdb

Tags: c, debugging, unix, gdb, pipe

I've written Unix Pipes but I don't have the good result.

I'm wondering if it's possible to debugging Unix pipe in C langage with gdb.
If no, do you know a method to do that ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use netcat with the -U switch. You will be able to create a listen/sender, or sit in between.

Comment: When I run the C program with pipes, I open a console and type netcat -U and it will show the pipe's content ? i only know netcat for network.

Comment: For example, nc -lkU /tmp/mysock would create a local socket at /tmp/mysock and output what it receives to stdout